# glenable(0)-What does this mean?

Tags: opengl-es

Could some explain it.
This didn't helped me:
http://www.khronos.org/opengles/documentation/opengles1_0/html/glEnable.html

Comment: You shouldn't count on the title to make up your question. Please ask a complete question in the actual question body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as no valid GL enum has an actual value of 0 (which I really doubt), this will result in a `GL_INVALID_ENUM` error and otherwise do nothing.